# How to parse Yahoo BOSS API response

Tags: java, json, parsing, yahoo-boss-api

I have used the following Java code from Yahoo to get search results response (Go to: Java Example) in the following link: http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/boss_api_guide/codeexamples.html

I registered and got my OAuth consumer key and secret and inserted them in the code. I got the following output

[image]

I am totally new to dealing with Json response and parsing them. Can anybody help in how can I parse this response in order to get the search results ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a library like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert the Json response into Java objects and use it with ease.

Check this for a simple tutorial:

http://www.javabeat.net/2012/04/parsing-json-using-java-and-gson-library/